# How to access my modules in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, module

I created a project **test** using zend tool. Then I created a module **test**. Then I created **TestController** in **test** module.

Now when I access **test.dev/test/test/index**, it show following error.

```
Message: Invalid controller specified (test)
```

How to enable my modules in zend. I think I have to enable my **application.ini** or **Bootstrap.php**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your application.ini

```
resources.modules[] =
resources.frontController.defaultModule = test
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/"
```

You may not set the default one. Then all the URI-s will be /modulename/controllername/actionname. Having a default module allows you to omit the "/modulename" part.

For other objects access set the includePath-s and autoloadernamespaces in application.ini:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
autoloadernamespaces.form = "Form_"
```

And follow the Zend naming conthention then in this dir. Say, Form_User_Login class must be defined in `APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library/Form/User/Login.php"`

Comment: Thanks. You are setting it default, What if I have to craete many modules. And also I have to set this module like that it should access all models/forms/acl which are located outside modules directory.

Comment: I'll add the reply to the answer.

Comment: Ok. I am waiting for your edit.. And can we do this in **Bootstrap.php** ?

Comment: Yes. In Bootstrap.php you'd use http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php and the Zend_Loader API: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html

Answer (score 1):

With the help of accepted answer I found:

I just added the following line in **application.ini** and all modules are accessible using URLs:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

So now my **application.ini** is like this:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
;includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

**Note**:

**moduleDirectory** statement should be after **controllerDirectory** statement.

**Help**:

- [How to access my modules in Zend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001672/how-to-access-my-modules-in-zend/6001705#6001705)